# dealing with Streams and ContentProducer - Java

Tags: java, android, http

I'm pretty new to coding with streams but now I have to do it for more efficient Http coding.

Here is code that I wrote(not working) to get ContentProducer for HttpClient:

```
public static ContentProducer getContentProducer(final Context context, final UUID gId)
    {
        return new ContentProducer()
        {
            public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException
            {
                outputStream = new Base64.OutputStream(new FileOutputStream(StorageManager.getFileFromName(context, gId.toString())));

                outputStream.flush();
            }
        };
    }
```

I'm using Base64 streaming encoder from here: http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/
My goal is to use this function to provide data that I read from binary file to HttpClient as base64 encoded stream.

This is how I consume content producers:

```
private MyHttpResponse processPOST(String url, ContentProducer requestData)
    {
        MyHttpResponse response = new MyHttpResponse();

        try
        {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serviceURL + url);
            HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(requestData);
            request.setEntity(entity);

            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response.Body = mHttpClient.execute(request, handler);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException e)
        {

        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {

        }

        return response;
    }
```

I have another ContentProducer which works with GSON streamer(and it's working):

```
public ContentProducer getContentProducer(final Context context)
    {
        return new ContentProducer()
        {
            public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException
            {
                Gson myGson = MyGsonWrapper.getMyGson();
                JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                writer.beginObject();

                // stuff

                writer.endObject();

                writer.flush();
            }
        };
    }
```

My question is: How to make my first example work. Am I doing it correctly? Right now I get empty post on server side, so it seems like no data coming through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I believe that the issue is that you are being passed an `OutputStream` in your `ContentProviders` `writeTo()` method, and you are overwriting it with your own `OutputStream`.  The contract of that class/method probably requires you to write your data to the `OutputStream` passed to you.

Based on looking at the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/ContentProducer.html), I do not see a way for you to specify the `OutputStream` to use, so you will probably need to just write out the data of the file to the `OutputStream` that is passed in.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buf = createByteBufferFromFile(StorageManager.getFileFromName(context, gId.toString()));
    outputStream.write(buf);
    outputStream.flush();
}
```

Of course you will need to provide an implementation to the createByteBufferFromFile(...) method that I mention.  Again, you should note that it is not likely that you will be using the `Base64 OutputStream`, so if that is a necessity, then you may have to find a different approach.

Comment: How should I modify my first example to make it work? I need to pass ContentProducer with stream of Base64 from file

Comment: Just to clarify more - first example is my code. I'm trying to build producer with base64 encoded data from file.

Comment: So, is there an issue with your producer?  If so, what is the issue?  It is hard to help when there is little clarity to the question.  I would encourage you to edit the question to try to give us more detail as to what each code snippet is/means, what your issue is, and what you have tried...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's too bad. I need to find a way to stream base64 encoded data. Loading file into memory just doesn't work with small RAM. I need to upload big images..